# Python: Get user's last login date time of jira

Tags: python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I use below code to fetch jira user details for the project:

```
user_details_response = requests.request("GET", self.JIRA_URL + "rest/api/2/user/assignable/multiProjectSearch?projectKeys=" + jira_project_key, headers=headers, params=query, auth=(user_name, password))
json_user_details  = json.loads(user_details_response.text)
```

I then use  below code to get details in list:

```
user_details= []
for user_details in json_user_details  :
    for key, value in user_details.items():
        if key == "name":
            user_key = value
        if key == "displayName":
            display_name = value
        if key == "emailAddress":
            email_address = value
        if key == "active":
            is_user_active = value
user_details.append((user_key, display_name, email_address, str(is_user_active)))
```

Now, I have to get user's login details also for the project. I tried to find information on [Python jira documentation](http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/), but, could not find any useful info.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the last login date time from the current JIRA API. You can get that information directly [via the database](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/retrieve-last-login-dates-for-users-from-the-database-363364638.html?_ga=2.127886862.2044672265.1568900474-596257740.1548408320) or [via Crowd](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowdkb/list-the-last-login-date-for-all-users-in-crowd-218278872.html?_ga=2.127886862.2044672265.1568900474-596257740.1548408320).

There [exists a request to add the missing functionality to the API](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFCLOUD-64260?_ga=2.127886862.2044672265.1568900474-596257740.1548408320), you can put your vote to prioritise it.